# Survey builder: does this flow make sense?

Tags: surveys, customisation, flow

I'm adding a new feature to a survey builder product. It allows the user to choose the appropriate tone of voice for a phrase; the user would be able to decide which phrasing would best fit their survey.

Below is a flow for how this could work. Any insights on what to improve /consider?

[image: Four screenshots that show: 1. User sees a phrase; 2. User clicks on the phrase to see options based on tone of voice; 3. User selects an option; user sees the original phrase replaced by the option]

Comment: Hi Lorelei, just to confirm, is your software offering different suggestions for a phrase in the same language with a different tone of voice for each suggestion? Or is it suggesting phrases in a different language?

Comment: for the example above option no 1 but also option no 2 is to design - so both

Comment: What does the dropdown arrow do on the right?

Comment: And, is this in a website or app?

Comment: It is a data-driven platform for the HR sector. This part of the platform is responsible for building a survey for candidates during the recruitment and onboarding process. The arrow on the right opens the questions available responses (ie. multiple answer questions, single answer question, yes/ no question, 5-star rating, etc. )

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this flow is:

1. User clicks on the phrase to see options
2. User is presented with options that have a difference in tone
3. User clicks on an option to select it, and then clicks OK to apply it
4. The selected option replaces the original phrase

I think you don't need the OK button to confirm the option selection. The selection should trigger the dialog closure. It would be good to give the user a way to cancel and close the dialog if they don't want to select a choice. An "X" close icon could work.

If the suggested phrases get longer than a couple of words, that might get hard to read; you might want to stack phrases vertically.

Comment: yes, exactly. You're right regarding the close icon - I forgot about it. What about if the user clicks into on the phrase to see different options - what should happen with the input text of this field? I made it italic for now and change the color for gray to stress out that it's edited. Do you think it's enough?

Comment: I agree, the OK button seems like an unnecessary step. Intuitively I would think that only clicking the option would select it.

Comment: Tell me more about how a phrase becomes "suggestible". Does the user highlight it and then the system makes suggestions? Or does the system notice the phrase and highlight it?